# What is the fastest secure way to create html element and set multiple attributes to the element on the client side

Tags: performance, createelement, setattribute

Hi I am a node js devoleper ,I want to know about what is the fast and secure way to create html elements and set multiple attributes on it in client side
currently I am doing it with

```js
//looping through data got from the server 

data = [{id:1,topic:'topic1',content:'content'}]

data.forEach(d=>{     document.getElementById('container').innerHTML += ` <div id="${d.id}" class="class1 class2">
<p class="topic class3" >${d.topic}</p>
<p class="content class3" >${d.content}</p>
</div> `
})
```

```html
<body>
  <div id='container' > 
  </div>
</body>
```

Comment: You'll need to be careful about XSS attacks if the data you're putting in the HTML is from users - if one of the elements of `data` is eg `{..., content: "<script>alert("hacked")</script>"}` you'll run into problems. You could try [DOMPurify.santize](https://github.com/cure53/DOMPurify) to fix this. Other than that, you could use a templating engine (try searching "nodejs templating engine") which might make your code a little cleaner.

Comment: no buddy data from trusted source